# How to change the phone number value in the Android emulator. (over API31)

Tags: android-emulator, phone-number

How to change the phone number value in the Android emulator.

[image: emulator phone number]

Until API 30, i could change it using the emulator cli option -phone-number.

However, starting with API31, the -phone-number option does not work.

Is there an alternative?